# Desktop screen recording using Directshow - PushSourceDesktop

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

I am working on DirectShow.NET to avail webcam and desktop screen recording features. I am successful with webcam recording. Now, moving towards desktop screen recording I have done this:

1. Downloaded Windows SDK, compiled `push source` project and `pushsource.dll` is generated.
2. Registered `pushsource.dll` using `regsvr32`
3. Successfully able build the graph in `graphedit` using `PushSource Desktop Filter` and genrated AVI/asf file.

After all this now I want to do this using c# code, while trying to start development I am facing following problems as well as some doubts

1. I referenced `DirectShowLib-2005.dll` in my project, but didn't know how can I add `PushSource Desktop Filter` into graph (ICaptureGraphBuilder2 n IFilterGraph2)
2. I have tried to reference `pushsource.dll` but not successful.
3. At the time of deployment of application on client machine, do I need to perform `regsvr32 pushsource.dll` step on client machine also?

Comment: `1` See DirectShow.NET samples, [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/directshownet/discussion/460697/thread/19d9cea2/) in particular, `2` behavior by design - no type library, `3` you don't but if you load filter explicitly, otherwise if you pick it up by CLSID then you do.

Comment: @RomanR., Thanks for reply. I have build the push source library from windows SDK and registered using `regsvr32` because currently I am creating instance using CLSID `4EA6930A-2C8A-4AE6-A561-56E4B5044437`. profile get loaded successfully and desktop recording is working but video seems very slow and mouse pointer is not visible in video also quality of video is also low. I am using `asf` writer to genrate `wmv` video, any guidance on this from you?

Comment: You need to paint cursor image yourself. This way of desktop capture is slow by design (it is rather a sample), software which uses faster desktop sharing uses more sophisticated options like display mirror drivers.

Comment: @RomanR. oh! so for normal/faster desktop sharing/recording `Directshow` will not help? or is it like "display mirror drivers" are part of `Directshow`

Comment: DirectShow does not offer you out of the box solution. It offers codecs and support for file formats. It does not offer you efficient desktop grabbing tools.